# Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference in IE 11

Tags: javascript, telerik-editor

There is functionality to find the caret(^) symbol in Telerik editor, I have searched over internet , i found few links ,they recommended to replace getSelection() instead of selection

> var range = editor.get_document().getSelection().createRange();

but unfortunatly it is not working.

Actual code

```
   var range = editor.get_document().selection.createRange();
            var oRange = range.duplicate();
            oRange.collapse(false);
            if (oRange.findText("^")) {
                oRange.select();
            }
            else {
                editor.set_html("");
                editor.set_html(currentHtml);
                oRange.findText("^")
                oRange.select();
            }
```

error :Unable to get property 'createRange' of undefined or null reference

Updated code :

```
  var range = editor.get_document().getSelection().createRange();
                var oRange = range.duplicate();
                oRange.collapse(false);
                if (oRange.findText("^")) {
                    oRange.select();
                }
                else {
                    editor.set_html("");
                    editor.set_html(currentHtml);
                    oRange.findText("^")
                    oRange.select();
                }
```

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createRange' 
how can fix it.

Comment: Your code shows `.selection` instead of `.getSelection()`. The editor object has no `.selection` property.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when modified to .getSelection().

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you are  running. As it stands now, the error message and code do not correspond.

Comment: [createRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange) documentation suggests it's a property of `Document`, not `Selection` object. have you tried `editor.get_document().createRange()` ? or use [`addRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange) method on the selection?

Comment: when I changed that , it says Object doesn't support property or method 'duplicate' @Aprillion

Comment: eeeh, [`cloneRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/cloneRange)?

Comment: @Aprillion now it says "Object doesn't support property or method 'findText' " but it was worked fine in IE 10.

Comment: welcome to web development and the beloved IE browser... I'm afraid none of the standard [`Range` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) are similar to `findText`, I suggest you to describe the problem (business logic) you are trying to solve in plain english - something should happen if the user selects text that contains ^ in some editor???

Comment: when user press F2 , have to select(highlight) the caret(^) symbol in Telerik Editor contents.